# GPO not applying default file associations

Tags: group-policy, xml, adobe

so I've exported a default association file as XML using DISM from a PC to use as a template. I placed the XML file on a share drive and created a GPO and went to

```
Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > File Explorer > Set a default associations configuration file
```

I enabled the setting and linked the location on the share drive where I put the XML file but it doesn't apply on a target PC.

I have already setup a GPO to edit the start-menu and taskbar layout which references an XML file in the exact same share drive folder, so it can't be an issue with read access can it?

Comment: What happens if you put that XML on a local computer and apply it through Local Group Policy? What is the OS you are applying to? Does XML file looks like it's suppose to when you inspect it?

Comment: OS is Windows 10 pro, the XML file looks perfect, both the generated template file and the copied file on the share drive. How do you locally apply the XML file?

Comment: You apply it locally the same way like on the DC just through "GPEDIT.msc". Or even better, import it through DISM and see if everything works OK ... Dism.exe /Online /Import-DefaultAppAssociations:"%PathToXML%". If everything works then it's the GPO and concentrate on that. If not, then there is something wrong with the XML file.